# Yearly reports shows different dates

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

i would like to ask how we can fix our project in vb we are currently on the yearly and monthly reports generation but when we choose a date outside the year 2022 it still shows the 2022 data for that month. here is our code that we use

```
Dim cr1 As New CrystalReport1
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select Date, Customer_No, Table_No, Order_ID, Total_Amount from SalesTable5 where Date between '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "' and '" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "' order by Date desc", con)
Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
cr1.SetDataSource(dt)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1
CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: First of all concatenate SQL queries is the way to be victim of an SQL injection attack, use parametrized queries ALWAYS.
And second what are the values of DateTimePicker1.Text and DateTimePicker2.Text? surely they aren't in the correct SQL format

Comment: Inspect the value of the query command after you've created it, then copy and paste it into a new management studio query which will highlight syntax errors.  But then as previous comment, using parameters in your query, I doubt you would of even had this issue